# sql detect cycle in directed graph

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a directed graph represented by an edge table. How can we detect the cycle in pure SQL ?

```
CREATE TABLE edges(id integer primary key identity, from_node int, to_node int);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_edges_of2 ON edges(from_node);

INSERT INTO edges(from_node,to_node) VALUES(1,2),(2,3),(3,1);
```

Comment: I note this appears to be a “normal” SQL Server table, rather than a SQL Server Graph DB table - have you considered using a Graph table? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is a recursive CTE.  However, for this to work, you need to keep a list of visited nodes.  SQL Server doesn't have an elegant solution for this (such as arrays), so you need to use string manipulations.

The following will list the cycles in the graph:

```
with cte as (
      select from_node, to_node, 
             convert(varchar(max), concat(',', from_node, ',', to_node, ',')) as nodes, 1 as lev, 
             (case when from_node = to_node then 1 else 0 end) as has_cycle
      from edges e
      union all
      select cte.from_node, e.to_node,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(cte.nodes, e.to_node, ',')), lev + 1,
             (case when cte.nodes like concat('%,', e.to_node, ',%') then 1 else 0 end) as has_cycle
      from cte join
           edges e
           on e.from_node = cte.to_node
      where cte.has_cycle = 0 
     )
select *
from cte
where has_cycle = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=676d928c65eeb7cc51e8d7cb26bd4fad) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: Interesting that this lists [2,3,1,2], [3,1,2,3] and [1,2,3,1]. I wonder if these should be counted as the same loop?

Comment: "SQL Server doesn't have an elegant solution for this (such as arrays), so you need to use string manipulations." <-- this really doesn't seem right to me, can't we use a table-valued-variable or even a `#temptable` for storing the set of visited nodes? What about `hierarchyid` too? (Even using a `CURSOR` with an entire table-lock feels more _correct_ than massive string concatenation in T-SQL)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CAST('.1.' AS varchar(1000)) AS gpath, 1 AS current_node, 0 AS Cycle

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(gpath, '.', e.to_node, '.') AS varchar(1000)) AS gpath, e.to_node AS current_node, 0 AS cycle
    FROM cte
    JOIN edges AS e ON e.from_node = cte.current_node
    WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT('.',e.to_node,'.'),cte.gpath)=0 AND cte.Cycle=0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(gpath, '.', e.to_node, '.') AS varchar(1000)) AS gpath, e.to_node AS current_node, 1 AS cycle
    FROM cte
    JOIN edges AS e ON e.from_node = cte.current_node
    WHERE CHARINDEX(CONCAT('.',e.to_node,'.'),cte.gpath)>0 AND cte.Cycle=0
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

gpath   current_node    Cycle

.1.     1     0

.1..2.  2   0

.1..2..3.   3   0

.1..2..3..1.    1   1