# Find loops within data using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following data to find the loop.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblLoop
(
    person1 varchar(20),
    person2 varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO tblLoop VALUES('A','B'),('A','C'),('A','D'),
                          ('B','E'),('B','F'),
                          ('D','G'),('D','H'),
                          ('F','i'),
                          ('G','J'),
                          ('i','A'),
                          ('J','D');
```

Edit: Added some more values

```
INSERT INTO tblLoop VALUES('X','Y'),('X','Z'),('Z','X'),('Y','W');
```

Records Look like:
[image]
[image]

**Note**: There is possibility of multiple trees like above we need to find all trees loop data.

Requirement: I need to find the persons which forms a loop. For an example in the given data we found 2 Loop's:

Loop 1: `A` connected with `B` connected with `F` connected with `i` connected with `A`.

Loop 2: `A` connected with `D` connected with `G` connected with `J` connected with `D`.

Expected result:

```
LoopFound
--------------------
A->B->F->i->A
A->D->G->J->D
X->Z->X
```

My try:

```
;WITH CTE_Loop AS 
(
    SELECT  t.Person1,t.Person2,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), t.Person1 + '->' + t.Person2) AS [Loop],
            0 AS FoundFlag
    FROM tblLoop t 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Person1,t.Person2,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), cte.[Loop] +'->'+t.Person2) AS [Loop],
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(t.Person2, cte.[Loop]) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FoundFlag
    FROM CTE_Loop cte
    INNER JOIN tblLoop t ON t.Person1 = cte.Person2
    WHERE cte.FoundFlag = 0  AND t.Person1 <> '-' AND t.Person2 <> '-'
)
SELECT [Loop] AS LoopFound
FROM CTE_Loop 
WHERE FoundFlag = 1 
GROUP BY [Loop];
```

Comment: This is a graph. You're looking for cycles in the graph loops. X,Y,Z etc are called Nodes, and the transitions Edges. If you use the correct terms, it's easier to google for solutions. SQL Server 2017 [added graph support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If you google for `T-SQL Cycle in graph` you'll find various solutions and similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849394/sql-detect-cycle-in-directed-graph). The answer in this case uses recursive CTEs, which *are* available in SQL Server 2012

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I tried with CTE as you mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849394/sql-detect-cycle-in-directed-graph but the result is getting all combination of cycle's. I am just looking for the loops which I have mentioned.

Comment: Looks like you tried the CTE technique. It will work if you remove `AND t.Person1 <> '-' AND t.Person2 <> '-'` from the recursive part of the CTE. Is the *real* question perhaps, how to avoid cycles with the same nodes?

Comment: In that case, your *real* question is quite different. You should ask that - how to eliminate similar cycles. Your query (without the problematic part) produces `X->Z->X` and `Z->X->Z`. It's the same cycle, starting from a different node

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, My bad! And yeah "how to eliminate similar cycles" actually I am looking for. And I have `date column` too in that table which can easily sort `X,Z` and then `Z,X` entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
   CONCAT_WS('->',t1.person1,t1.person2,t2.person2 ,t3.person2,t4.person2) 
FROM tblLoop t1
left join tblLoop t2 on t1.person2 = t2.person1
left join tblLoop t3 on t2.person2 = t3.person1
left join tblLoop t4 on t3.person2 = t4.person1
where t1.person1 = 'A'AND t4.person2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `CONCAT_WS` seems to be new in SQL Server 2017 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql

Comment: its just string concadanate function. Use your sql version's concat function or +'->'+

Comment: @EmreB., Only one problem with your query is `t1.person1 = 'A'`, which is I don't know from where the tree has been started.

Comment: But I have the date column there! Is that gonna help?

Comment: @MAK if you dont know start point.Write a subquery there and use date column.t1.person1 = (select ......)

Comment: @EmreB., Okay! But when I get multiple trees like I said in note, how will be the subquery look like?

Comment: For an example `INSERT INTO tblLoop VALUES('X','Y'),('X','Z'),('Z','X'),('Y','W');` And expected result will be `X->Z->X`.

Comment: The problem is finding cycles in a connected graph. A simple JOIN can't do this. This query for example can only find cycles that are exactly 4 nodes long. It won't find `X-Z` or `D-G-J`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the start&end of the loops assuming a hierarchy of some sort(eg. A comes before B which is before C etc) and exclude rows whose person2 does not appear as person1 (i.e the ends of the relation/chain)...

```
--get loops
select  distinct a.person1, b.person1, b.person2  --a.person1, b.person1 :: loop range(start-end)
from tblLoop as a
join tblLoop as b on a.person1 = b.person2 and a.person1 <= b.person1 --assume a hierarchy by name (A is on a higher/or equal level than B etc)
where exists(select * from tblLoop as d where d.person1 = a.person2) --exclude dead ends (person2 which is not person1);
```

..and inject that into the cte. You could work out overlaps and loops without the same start&end.

(for eg. A->D->G->J->D or D->G->J->D is a loop?)

```
;WITH CTE_Loop AS 
(
    SELECT  t.Person1,t.Person2,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), t.Person1 + '->' + t.Person2) AS [Loop],
            0 AS FoundFlag
    FROM tblLoop t 
    where t.person1 in 
    (
        select  distinct a.person1--, b.person1, b.person2  --a.person1, b.person1 :: loop range(start-end)
        from tblLoop as a
        join tblLoop as b on a.person1 = b.person2 and a.person1 <= b.person1 --assume a hierarchy by name (A is on a higher/or equal level than B etc)
        where exists(select * from tblLoop as d where d.person1 = a.person2) --exclude dead ends (person2 which is not person1)     
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Person1,t.Person2,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), cte.[Loop] +'->'+t.Person2) AS [Loop],
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(t.Person2, cte.[Loop]) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FoundFlag
    FROM CTE_Loop cte
    INNER JOIN tblLoop t ON t.Person1 = cte.Person2
    WHERE cte.FoundFlag = 0  AND t.Person1 <> '-' AND t.Person2 <> '-'
)
SELECT [Loop] AS LoopFound
FROM CTE_Loop 
WHERE FoundFlag = 1 
GROUP BY [Loop];
```